# Naming cameras/shots in list with the same frame ranges in Maya using Python

Tags: python, maya

Currently if I have 2 cameras covering the same sequence time then, there should be two different shot exports with the same camera name e.g. It should be with this naming:

- cam1_shot1_10-35.fbx
- cam1_shot2_10-35.fbx
- cam2_shot1_34-64.fbx
- cam2_shot2_34-64.fbx

how can i achieve this in Maya Python?

Comment: Do you want to know how to create the names or how to export the scene to fbx?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to know how to create the naming. Probably using for loops with counter? or if you have any other methods in mind. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the data from somewhere, here's an example of how you can wrangle the output. For the record, this is not a Maya problem but a straight up simple logic/Python problem.

```
file_names = []
cams = [
    'cam1',
    'cam2',
]
shots = [
    'shot1',
    'shot2',
]
ranges = [
    (10, 35),
    (34, 64),
]
for cam, frange in zip(cams, ranges):
   for shot in shots:
       file_name = '{}_{}_{}-{}'.format(cam, shot, frange[0], frange[1])
       file_names.append(file_name)

for file_name in file_names:
    print file_name

>>> cam1_shot1_10-35
>>> cam1_shot2_10-35
>>> cam2_shot1_34-64
>>> cam2_shot2_34-64
```